# How to upload files programmatically to SharePoint from Linux?

Tags: sharepoint-online, curl

I'm looking to automate the upload of files to SharePoint from a UNIX system. I see that SharePoint no longer supports NTLM and needs either Claims-Based Identity (SAML) or OAuth flow, thus rendering this solution ineffective

```
curl -k --ntlm --user user:password --upload-file test.txt https://company.sharepoint.com/ --verbose
```

I would like to avoid implementing SAML or OAuth because of the extra developing time this would result in. Are there any alternative solutions for Unix users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately security is something you need to deal with in remote scenarios such as this. Usually it's most of the effort.

You have two options:

- Figure out how to implement the security yourself
- Use a third party library that already handles this

I don't know anything about curl so I can't be much help there. But I do know that Node.JS works on Linux systems and I do know that the NPM module `spsave` works brilliantly, so I recommend looking into that. It supports a number of authentication scenarios, has decent documentation, and is authored by someone who frequents this site.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/spsave